# Python hold button when image detect

Tags: python, button, keyboard

i want to make a simple script in python, but i just don't know why it don't work.
I want to hold a button when a image is detected

Right now i have this:

```
while 1:
    if pyautogui.locateOnScreen('arriba.png', confidence=0.8) != None:
        pyautogui.keyUp('left')
        pyautogui.keyUp('right')
        pyautogui.keyUp('down')
        pyautogui.keyDown('up')
        print('up')
    else:
        if pyautogui.locateOnScreen('abajo.png', confidence=0.8) != None:
            pyautogui.keyUp('left')
            pyautogui.keyUp('right')
            pyautogui.keyUp('up')
            pyautogui.keyDown('down')
            print('down')
        else:
            if pyautogui.locateOnScreen('left.png', confidence=0.8) != None:
                pyautogui.keyUp('up')
                pyautogui.keyUp('right')
                pyautogui.keyUp('down')
                pyautogui.keyDown('left')
                print('left')
            else:
                if pyautogui.locateOnScreen('right.png', confidence=0.8) != None:
                    pyautogui.keyUp('left')
                    pyautogui.keyUp('up')
                    pyautogui.keyUp('down')
                    pyautogui.keyDown('right')
                    print('right')
                else:
                    time.sleep(0.1)
                    print("nada")
```

But when the image is detected it just press the button 1 time, and it's not holding it. Thanks!

Comment: use `elif` instead of `else: if` to make code more readable.

Comment: I have similar problem, i think this will be helpful:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74198333/how-to-hold-a-button-using-python