# How to hold a button using Python

Tags: python, keyboard, pyautogui

I need to hold button ("A") for few seconds. I tried lots of libs and methods, but nothing not works. Every exemples what I tried was identical("A" pressed by one time, dont hold)

This is my code:

```
import pyautogui as pag
import time

pag.keyDown("a")
time.sleep(10)
pag.keyUp("a")
```

But it does not work. "A" pressed only one time, but i need to hold it.
I need not just one "A", but something like this: "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"

Please help me anyone

Comment: It must be like this: https://www.mediafire.com/file/9qy83sv0qgyzrlo/ApplicationFrameHost_dLn37HnFIy.mp4/file This is just video of what i need

Answer (score 0):

From the `pyautogui.keyDown()` documentation: it "performs a keyboard key press without the release." So this should put that key in a held down state.

For sequential pressing, try

```
import time, pyautogui
hold_time = 10
start = time.time()
while time.time() - start < hold_time:
    pyautogui.press('A')
```

Comment: It not works. It just press lot of times to "A". But I need to hold "A"

Comment: As explained, `keyDown("a")` holds the key until you `keyUp("a")`. Whatever is that your code understands as "holding a key", should probably be revisited.

Comment: Yes, keyDown holds the key, but "A" writes only one time. I thinked that "A" be holled and writes multiple, not once

Answer (score 0):

```
import time
import pyautogui

def press_and_hold(hold_on):

    start_time = time.time()

    while True:

        pyautogui.press("A")
                
        time_now = time.time()
        if (time_now-start_time)>=hold_on:
            break
```

For Running in another window, multithreading can be used:

```
import time
import pyautogui
import os
import threading

def press_and_hold(hold_on):

    start_time = time.time()

    while True:

        pyautogui.press("A")
                
        time_now = time.time()
        if (time_now-start_time)>=hold_on:
            break


t1 = threading.Thread(target=os.system, args=("notepad", ))
t2 = threading.Thread(target=press_and_hold, args=(10, ))

t1.start()
t2.start()

t2.join()
t1.join()
```

Comment: This code also just press lot of times "A" button. Not hold